# Google Data Studio: Show individual value instead of sum

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have written query in bigdata like this to show average session.

```
select  dd, mm, SUM(total_sessions) AS Total_Sessions, AVG(sess_length_seconds) AS Average_Session_Duration from (
  SELECT dd, mm, user_pseudo_id, sess_id, MIN(min_time) sess_start, MAX(max_time) sess_end, COUNT(*) records, 
    MAX(sess_id) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id) total_sessions,
    (ROUND((MAX(max_time)-MIN(min_time))/(1000*1000),1)) sess_length_seconds
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(session_start) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY min_time) sess_id
    FROM (
      SELECT *, IF(previous IS null OR (min_time-previous) > (20*60*1000*1000), 1, 0) session_start 
      FROM (
        SELECT *, LAG(max_time, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY max_time) previous
        FROM (SELECT  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) as mm, EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) as dd, user_pseudo_id, MIN(event_timestamp) AS min_time, MAX(event_timestamp) AS max_time
          FROM `alive-ios.analytics_160092165.events_201810*` 
          GROUP BY mm, dd, user_pseudo_id)
      )
    )
  )
  GROUP BY 1, 2,3, 4
  ORDER BY 1, 2 

)

GROUP BY dd, mm
ORDER BY dd, mm desc
LIMIT 10
```

[image]

Problem is in data studio, it only have option "sum" or average, etc. As a result, instead of showing individual row, it always show combined result. How shall I do to show individual row?

[image]

Comment: I tested this and it works fine for me at least. It doesn't sum it up because it's already been aggregated. Can you share a screen shot of the result?

Answer (score 0):

In data studio you should be including it as a dimension not metric.

Comment: Problem is it doesn't let me choose as dimension. Is there any requirement to become dimension?

Comment: It should allow you to just drag it into a dimension slot on any graph or table. If not then go to edit the dataset, duplicate the metrics and then set the aggregation to "none"